# openssl s_client returns errono=54 to github.com

Tags: macos, ssl, certificate, openssl

I'm trying to execute this commands:

```
openssl s_client -connect github.com:443
openssl s_client -connect github.com:443 -servername github.com
```

But I got in both:

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
write:errno=54
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 316 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I'm working behind a proxy in a MacOS BigSur. The interesting is that using `curl` works normally: `curl https://github.com` returns github html page.

Another important thing is that if I enter in github.com in my chrome I got my proxy company certificate as CA for github public certificate. Inside my macos I already installed all CA certificates inside Keychan App but didn't worked.

Comment: Probably OpenSSL uses a CA store which doesn't trust your company's CA. You'd have to add their CA to your OpenSSL CA store. Depending on how you installed OpenSSL, this might work: https://akrabat.com/syncing-macos-keychain-certificates-with-homebrews-openssl/

Comment: I tried the first option, using the security command line to generate a new cert.pem, replaced this cert.pem in openssl folder , restart terminal, but didn't work, the problem continue.

Comment: I tried the second solutions, using brew services start openssl-osx-ca, but didn't worked also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`errno=54` means that the connection was reset by the peer (ECONNRESET) or some device claiming to be the peer. Given that your infrastructure uses a proxy it is likely that the proxy is the cause of the problem.

> Inside my macos I already installed all CA certificates inside Keychan App but didn't worked.

This does not help since it is not the local code having problems to check the server certificate. It does not even get the server certificate for verification which can be seen from the following output:

> SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 316 bytes

This means that the TCP connection was successful, the ClientHello was written (316 bytes) but nothing received (0 bytes) which implicitly also no server certificate received. This kind of behavior is common with DPI based firewalls.

> The interesting is that using curl works normally ...

curl and the browser might use an explicit proxy, in which case they will do a CONNECT request to build a tunnel through the proxy and not directly connect to the website. Check the `https_proxy`, `http_proxy`, `HTTPS_PROXY` or `HTTP_PROXY` variables. `openssl s_client` instead does not use a proxy.

Comment: So, if openssl s_client don't use proxy, this can be the problem. How can I force openssl to use proxy to test it ?

Comment: I just added -proxy in my openssl command and now worked. Thanks Steffen